# How to @import external SCSS properly with webpack and Vue.js?

Tags: sass, webpack, vue.js

As in Material Component Web's example, I want to be able to import SCSS from my `node_modules` like this:

```
@import '@material/elevation/mdc-elevation';
```

However, I'm getting this error message when trying to run the webpack build:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: @material/elevation/mdc-elevation.
```

`@import './~/@material/elevation/mdc-elevation.scss';` doesn't work either.

I'm pretty sure the issue is somewhere in my webpack config, but I can't figure out where.

**What did they do in [Material Components Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web)'s [Vue.js example](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/framework-examples/vue) in order to make it work?**

Here's my [npm-debug.log](https://hastebin.com/omosazecay) in case you need it.
And here's the corresponding Git repository: [sk22/spg-tinf-sem03/proj01](https://github.com/sk22/spg-tinf-sem03/tree/master/proj01)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I want to be able to import the **scss** files, not the compiled css.

Comment: try `@import '~/@material/elevation/mdc-elevation';`

Comment: @sobolevn That doesn't work either. However, the example linked imports it using `@material/elevation/mdc-elevation`, so that should also work somehow.

Comment: Have a look at this simple example: https://github.com/wemake-services/vue-material-button/blob/master/src/components/MaterialButton.vue#L72

Comment: There it is: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/framework-examples/vue/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L24-L26

Comment: @HashemQolami I've already added this (as a webpack 2 [rule option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-options-rule-query)) to my config, since the linked example uses webpack 1. I've also tried to add the sassLoader object, but it also didn't work.

Comment: @sobolevn Importing the compiled css file with the `~` prefix works. But I want to import the scss to make use of mixins provided by MDC. (Omitting the `~` is minor, but it should work, as it also does in the example, shouldn't it?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Got it.

here's a part of my webpack 2 config's `module.rules`:

```
{
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

So what did I do wrong?
My `options` object was placed in the rule directly, not the loader.

The old webpack config rule looked like this:

```
{
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  options: { includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')] },
},
```

See the difference? Instead of the 'sass-loader' string, I extended it to an object, containing the `loader` name and the `options` object, because the `options` only apply to the `sass-loader`.

(You could also drop the path.resolve and only write 'node_modules', but it might be safer to leave it.)

Check out this documentation page for further information. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-use

Without that loader, you must prefix each import with a `~`, which webpack converts to the `node_modules` folder, at least with my previous configuration.
But this will break 3rd party SCSS frameworks like [Material Components Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web), because they use `@import` statements without a leading `~` themselves, for example [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/packages/mdc-button/mdc-button.scss#L17).

**Inside .vue files**

This will not work in .vue files, as `vue-loader` just uses sass-loader **without any options** by default.
So if you want that to work, you probably need to make use of vue-loader's own options, as described [in its documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/options.html#loaders).

(I'm unable to get it to work for some reason I don't know...)

Comment: Inside .vue files working configuration: https://github.com/Bobarev/vue-mdc-adapter-webpack-simple/blob/master/template/webpack.config.js#L48

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: Webpack has a section on sass-loader now: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/ also mentioning includepaths.

I had the same issue with @material and Vue. I managed to resolve the problem without adjusting the `use` property directly.

**Solution**

**Step 1**: First create a default Vue 2.1 project using the CLI.
  Your file structure will have a `./build` directory.

**Step 2**: Open the file 'utils' you will see a `cssLoaders()` function which returns an object/map for the languages `vue-loader` supports.

You will see both `sass` and `scss` in that map.

**Step 3**: Change the values of `sass` and `scss` to:

```
  sass:    generateLoaders('sass', {
    indentedSyntax: true,
    includePaths:   [path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
  }),
    scss:    generateLoaders('sass', {
  includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
}),
```

**Step 4**: Go to the .vue file you're using and change the `lang` attribute in your `<style>` element to either `sass` or `scss`.

**Step 5**: After you've done that go to the terminal/console and install `sass-loader` with:

npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev

**Step 6**: Then run `npm run dev` and it should work.

**Why does this work?**

**Libraries**

I dug around a bit and it turns out [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) uses [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) which has some options such as`includePaths` one mentioned by @22samuelk. IncludePaths tells node-sass or rather the underlying library [LibSass](https://github.com/sass/libsass) to include sass files from that directory/path.

**Vue**

***Sass-loader options***

By default Vue expects your assets to be in your projects `src/assets` folder (correct me if I'm wrong). You can however use `~` to indicat you want to start at your projects root which would look like `~/node_modules/@material/smth/mdc-smth.scss.

Now if you want your sass-loader to use something other than those options you need to explicitly tell them.

Hence `path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules'` since the `utils` file is in `./build` and you need to use an absolute path for `sass-loader` to understand where to look.

***Vue-loader config***

This is not really specific to the question but the vue-loader config defined in `vue-loader.conf.js` works as follows:

It uses the map returned by `cssLoaders()` to build the loaders expected by webpack.
  The returned map (`{key:value}`) is then used by providing `key` as a file extension used in `test:` for a loader object. The `value` is used as the loader  object.
  Which would like like this:

```
{
  test: /\.(key)$/,
    use: [
  {
    loader: '//ld//-loader',
    options: {
      /*Options passed to generateLoaders('//ld//', options)*/
    },
  },
],
}
```

Where `key` is the file extention. In this case that would be either `sass` or `scss`. And `//ld//`is the loader you which to use. Which is shown in **Step 3** as `'sass'`.

Hopefully this clears up some stuff. Took me a while because I just started using Vue.