# How to use include paths with Vue CLI, when trying to import sass modules?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli, sass-loader

I'm starting a new project using the Vue CLI, and this is my first time using it.

I'm using a CSS framework (Spectre), which I installed via NPM. I'm now trying to import only parts of it. I have found a way to get it to work, but it's quite cumbersome, and I'd like to find a better way using the `includePaths` option.

Basically, the whole thing can be summarized like this: I have a `*.scss` file that looks like this:

```css
@import "./node_modules/spectre.css/src/accordions";
@import "./node_modules/spectre.css/src/avatars";
@import "./node_modules/spectre.css/src/badges";
@import "./node_modules/spectre.css/src/breadcrumbs";
...
```

and I obviously want to simplify it by removing the `./node_modules/spectre.css/src/` part from all the imports.

In `vue.config.js`, here's what I have:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/spectre.css/src')]
} } } }
```

But that doesn't work.

I've looked at the following questions:

- [How to @import external SCSS properly with webpack and Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368263/how-to-import-external-scss-properly-with-webpack-and-vue-js/44353756)
- [Webpack-simple + vue-cli with SASS - Can't compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490969/webpack-simple-vue-cli-with-sass-cant-compile)
- [Using sass-resources-loader with vue-cli v3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086021/using-sass-resources-loader-with-vue-cli-v3-x)

But couldn't find an answer, or couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The [URL transform rules of Vue CLI projects](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules) allow using `~` as a path alias into the project's `node_modules/`, so you could do:

```css
@import "~spectre.css/src/accordions";
@import "~spectre.css/src/avatars";
@import "~spectre.css/src/badges";
@import "~spectre.css/src/breadcrumbs";
```

No changes to your Vue config is needed.

Comment: I'm aware, but I'd like to find a way to just do `@import "accordions";`. This is also a matter of understanding how it works for future projects.